# How to show left associativity in a LL1 grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

Properties of LL(1) grammars

```
 Ambiguous grammars can’t be LL(1) 
  Left recursive grammars can’t be LL(1)  
 A grammar with common prefixes can’t be LL(1)
```

In an expression which has subtraction operation, to include the left associativity, we have to write it in left recursive way(so that it is unambiguous). Now thegrammar is unambiguous, but also left recursive. Now how do I parse it using a LL1 predictive parser(because LL1 grammars cant be left recursive).

Answer (score 0):

In many cases we can transform the original left-recursive grammar into an equivalent one that can be parsed by a LL(1) parser:

- <del>http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/hamel/courses/2013/fall2013/csc402/lecture-notes/csc402-ln005.pdf</del>

  - http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/hamel/courses/2015/fall2015/csc402/lecture-notes/csc402-ln005.pdf

I think this is covered by many lecture notes and textbooks because it's such a important topic for practitioners.

If you need more details, you might as well post a new question to

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem that I think @DesirePRG was referring  to is that after you remove left-recursive rules, the parse tree created will not respect the left-associativity rule.

Comment: @user1635881 I updated the URL of the lecture note which briefly discusses one way to deal with that difficulty.